# awk: catch `exit' in the END block

Tags: awk

I'm using `awk` for formatting an input file in an output file. I have several patterns to fill variables (like "some pattern" in the example). These variables are printed in the required format in the `END` block. The output has to be done there because the order of appearance in the input file is not guaranteed, but the order in the output file must be always the same.

```
BEGIN {
    FS = "=|,"
}


/some pattern/ {
    if ($1 == 8) {
        var = $1
    } else {
        # Incorrect field value
        exit 1
    }
}

END {
    # Output the variables
    print var
}
```

So my problem is the `exit` statement in the pattern. If there is some error and this command is invoked, there should be no output at all or at the most an error message. But as the gawk manual ([here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Exit-Statement.html)) says, if the `exit` command is invoked in a pattern block the `END` block will be executed at least. Is there any way to catch the `exit` like:

```
if (!exit_invoked) {
    print var
}
```

or some other way to avoid printing the output in the `END` block?

Stefan

**edit:** Used the solution from shellter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you'll have to handle it explicitly, by setting `exit_invoked` before `exit` line, i.e.

```
BEGIN {
    FS = "=|,"
}


/some pattern/ {
    if ($1 == 8) {
        var = $1
    } else {
        # Incorrect field value
        exit_invoked=1
        exit 1
    }
}

END {
    if (! exit_invoked  ) {
        # Output the variables
        print var
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, dont't thought on this simple solution ;) I'will pack this in a function to not forget the `exit_invoked` set. Stefan

Comment: @Stefan : Good idea. As an reminder, that you have that variable in play, you might want to set in the BEGIN block, i.e. `exit_invoked=0`. Some will complain that it is unnecessary and redundant. I wouldn't do it myself, but it is a good self-documenting techinque. YRMV. Good luck.

Comment: I'll do this since I don't write the `awk` programm for myself. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
END {
      # If here from a main block exit error, it is unlikely to be at EOF
      if (getline) exit 
      # If the input can still be read, exit with the previously set status rather than run the rest of the END block.

      ......
```

Answer (score 0):

Being a fan of short syntax and trying to avoid futile `{}`s or adding them later to pre-existing programs, instead of:

```
...
    else {
        exit_invoked=1
        exit 1
    }
...
END {
    if (! exit_invoked  ) {
        print var
    }
}
```

I use:

```
    else 
        exit (e=1)            # the point
...
END {
    if(!e)
        print v
}
```